# Displaying MessageDialog using MVVM and Caliburn.Micro

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, windows-store-apps, caliburn.micro

I need to display a MessageDialog to the user if certain fields in the view are blank when they click a button to navigate. I can handle the input field validation from the view model just fine, I'm just not sure how to invoke a messagedialgo.showasync method from the view model and have it display on the view. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you used the IWindowManager interface? There is a WindowManager implementation in CM which you can use to show popups/dialogs etc. I'm not sure what it provides for windows8/store but it should do the job. Just take a dependency on IWindowManager and call ShowDialog() with an instance of the viewmodel that you want to fill the dialog, it should take care of the rest (afaik!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the sample and lib source of Caliburn.Micro. `IWindowManager` interface is only for WPF and Silverlight. For WinRT the sample contains this helper class.

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace Caliburn.Micro.WinRT.Sample.Results
{
    public class MessageDialogResult : ResultBase
    {
        private readonly string _content;
        private readonly string _title;

        public MessageDialogResult(string content, string title)
        {
            _content = content;
            _title = title;
        }

        public async override void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog(_content, _title);

            await dialog.ShowAsync();

            OnCompleted();
        }
    }
}
```

It can be called from viewmodel like this

`new MessageDialogResult("content", "title");`

See the code at CodePlex

[CoroutineViewModel.cs](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ae616b84192450d079cf8b6fb91f0d8b8cda4e6a#samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloWinRT/Caliburn.Micro.HelloWinRT/ViewModels/CoroutineViewModel.cs)

[MessageDialogResult.cs](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ae616b84192450d079cf8b6fb91f0d8b8cda4e6a#samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloWinRT/Caliburn.Micro.HelloWinRT/Results/MessageDialogResult.cs)